# How to load Django ListView via Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

Basically code works as I expected, but my ListView is not refreshing. Everything works fine, but template does not load itself, I must push reload button (all data are loaded correctly then).

I done simple form/input for testing and there is no problem with views. My project requires calendar widget for picking months, and simplest way to do this I found on the internet was Ajax approach.

Ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({

                        viewMode: 'months',
                        format: 'MM/YYYY',
                }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                    var url = "/booking/update_months/{{hotel_id}}";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            month: e.date.month(),
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        }
                    });
                })

            });
        });
```

Url "/booking/update_months/{{hotel_id}}" refers to first View function I'm using for this functionality:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_months(request, hotel_id):
    if request.GET.get('month'):
        month = request.GET.get('month')
        request.session['month'] = int(month) + 1
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('booking:hotel_statistics', args=(hotel_id,)))
    else:
        return render_to_response(request, 'booking/hotel_statistics.html')
```

Then in HotelStatistics ListView I'm doing some stuff in get_context_data function, nothing special here. Just by some "prints" I've tested that the code is being executed until the end of the class.

```
class HotelStatistics(ListView):
    model = Reservation
    context_object_name = 'reservations'
    template_name = 'booking/hotel_statistics.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    .
    .
    .
    return context
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something with Ajax functionality, It's my first approach to this language. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using AJAX here? Unless I am missing something, you should just have the date picker inside an HTTP GET form that is submitted.

*template.html*

```html
<!-- The action attribute hardcoded URL value should be replaced with a Django url templatetag. This will allow the url to be resolved based on the router configuration. i.e. {% url "booking:update_months" hotel_id %} --> 
<form action="/booking/update_months/{{ hotel_id }}" method="GET">
  <input id="date" name="date">
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date").datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'months',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  });
});
</script>
```

*view.py*

```py
@csrf_exempt
def update_months(request, hotel_id):
  date = request.GET.get("date")

  if date:
    request.session["month"] = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").month
    return redirect("booking:hotel_statistics", False, hotel_id)

  return render(request, "booking/hotel_statistics.html")
```

The code above submits an HTTP GET form, resulting in a server side 301 and therefore a "refresh" of your statistics page with the update session data.

Notice, we are sending up the full date information. I am not sure if you are doing this separately, but if you are allowing users to update each date part independent, you could now bring that together into a single `update_date` function.